# Can I check for any version of python 3+ on a linux box

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7, rpm

OS: CentOS

I'd like to deploy a python script as part of a larger package and any python3+ will do.  On the VMs we have here, I'm seeing python3, python36, python36u, and python34. I don't want to install a new python3+ if I don't have too, I want to install python3 if the box only has python2+.

Along the same lines, I want my use python3, python34, python36, or whatever else is sitting available.

I'm deploying with a .rpm, but I haven't had any luck managing this complexity in a spec file.  My work-around is to write a bash script to handle python detection and installation.

Is there a way to manage this?

edit - adding specifics about the package installs

PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

```
yum install -y python34
yum list installed | grep python3
# python34.x86_64                       3.4.10-2.el7                     @epel    
# python34-libs.x86_64                  3.4.10-2.el7                     @epel 
which python3 
# usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin)
which python3.4
# /usr/bin/python3.4
```

Comment: Ideally (if your distro people are doing The Right Thing), a properly-packaged `python34` or `python36` or whatever will *also* be available under the name `python3`, so you should always be able to just run `python3`.

Comment: if the command `which python3` does not return any result you know you have to install a version of python 3 if the os distribution does not provide a python version, that you need you might look at pyenv https://github.com/pyenv

Comment: See edit:  yum install python34 is not creating a python3 link.  I agree it should, but it's not currently under my control

Comment: Not an answer, but you can look at how bash-completion would work for `python3<tab><tab>`

Comment: Is python3x installed with a "python" link? then you could check the result of `python --version` Of course you might find that is version 2, even though you have 3x installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity, I will post my solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PYTHONS
export RVAL
PYTHONS=$(compgen -c | grep "^python3.*[0-9]*$")
RVAL=$?

if [ $RVAL -ne 0 ] ; then
  yum install -y python3
  PYTHON="python3"
else
  PYTHON=$(echo "$PYTHONS" | head -1)
fi

echo "$PYTHON"

$PYTHON myscript.py
```